# Pyexpat import error when running aws cli

Tags: linux, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I am having some problems running the aws cli on ubuntu 14.04
I keep getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 15, in <module>
import awscli.clidriver
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 16, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 27, in <module>
import botocore.credentials
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 23, in    <module>
from botocore.compat import total_seconds
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/compat.py", line 118, in <module>
import xml.etree.cElementTree
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/cElementTree.py", line 3, in <module>
from _elementtree import *
ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "pyexpat"
```

When I do

```
 ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/*/pyexpat*
```

I get

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69200 Mar 23 01:57 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Somehow the problem was I had to run the aws commands with sudo.

Comment: similar problem with StarCluster and sudo solved it, thanks

Comment: Please do give a feedback if you found the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I came across similar problem when I did xml parsing in Python (2.7). Finally, it was figured out that it was caused by the inaccurately defined `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Here was my situation: the xml parsing library: *libexpat.so* was confused with the MATLAB version (*libexpat.so.1.5.0*) between the system version (*libexpat.so.1.6.0*), the `ImportError` arose when loaded the MATLAB version *libexpat.so*, after I precisely defined the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that is excluding MATLAB library path, everything went smoothly.

Comment: That's right, just `setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '')` before your Matlab code

Comment: @PhùngĐôngHưng Define you ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` env with the path where your ``libexpat.so`` is, e.g. ``export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<your lib path>:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`` in your ``.bashrc`` file.