# Rosdep fails to import python module pyexpat

Tags: python, debian, ros, debian-jessie

I'm attempting to install ROS on Debian Jessie and I'm running into an error when I run `sudo rosdep init`. The instructions I'm following are at this URL (http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source). I'm installing from source and not though their repos because of some library conflicts.

Running `sudo rosdep init` results in the following output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 3, in <module>
    from rosdep2.main import rosdep_main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .installers import InstallerContext, Installer, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/installers.py", line 35, in <module>
    from rospkg.os_detect import OsDetect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .rospack import expand_to_packages, get_package_name, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 35, in <module>
    from xml.etree.cElementTree import ElementTree
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/cElementTree.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _elementtree import *
ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "pyexpat"
```

I figured that this was python simply not finding the module, so I took a look at where it was located and at python's path, to no avail.

```
[jwerner5@rockhopper:~ ] $$ find / -name pyexpat*
/usr/include/python2.7/pyexpat.h
/usr/include/python3.4m/pyexpat.h
/usr/share/jython/Lib/pyexpat.py
/usr/share/jython/Lib/pyexpat$py.class
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so

>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

So it's in the path. I next ran an `strace -e open rosdep` just make sure it was finding the file. Here's the output of that. It looks like it finds the file and then closes it immediately. Here's the relevant bit.

```
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/pyexpat.py", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/pyexpat.pyc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so", O_RDONLY) = 9
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

This question ([ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "pyexpat"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100149/importerror-pycapsule-import-could-not-import-module-pyexpat)) suggested that one try renaming the library, or reinstalling it. I have tried both of these things and neither has worked. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Since posting, as per forax's intructions, I have tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, done a manual import of pyexpat in a python shell, and taken a look at the output of ldd for pyexpat.

Manual import of pyexpat

```
    Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
    [GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import pyexpat
.
```

Running `ldd` on the pyexpat library

```
[jwerner5@rockhopper:~ ] $$ ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc069da000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f7214382000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7214165000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7213db9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055fe01ce4000)
```

Comment: Sounds like that question: [Pyexpat import error when running aws cli](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25934479/2938861)

Comment: @farax I tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try manual import in python shell and post the result.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyexpat
>>>
```

And check lib load, should look like this:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe82d10000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f6387386000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6387169000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6386dbd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005628bbd68000)
```

Comment: Manual import in a python shell returns no output; I assume that means that it is successful.

Running `ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` returns the exact same as what you have posted. Only the hex at the end of each line differs.

Comment: The standard python environment is fine and the libexpat lib is in place. I can't imagine that the set up change the libpath - have no idea.